# Moving a bag containing a Muktzeh item during Shabbat

Tags: shabbat, muktzeh

What is the halacha for a bag that contains a Muktzeh item on Shabbat while containing other non Muktzeh items? Can the bag be moved?

Example: a Tallit bag that contains a bag with Tfillin inside and one wants to move it somewhere else or pull the Tallit from inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what's more important; the muktzeh item or the permitted item(depending on the person's own preferences; subject to debate).

If the permitted item is more important, then it is permitted to move the bag because the muktzeh item is batel(insignificant) to the permitted items(unless the non-muktzeh items were placed as a base for the muktzeh item prior to shabbat). See Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 310:8-9.

If the forbidden item has more personal value or use to the person than the permitted items, then it would be forbidden to move the bag(ibid.).

In the case of a bag with a tallit and tefillin on shabbat; it is permitted to do both actions(moving the bag with both tallit and tefillin or pulling the tallit from inside) since the tallit is of more importance to the person and tefillin is not necessarily muktzeh(since there is a permit to wear them on shabbat if found in the desert; see Mishna Shabbat 19:23) Also see Yalkut Yosef Shabbat siman 310:187 below.

There are cholkim that hold it is muktzeh and require putting a sefer in the bag so that we are not mevatel kli(render the bag muktzeh) by making it a base for a muktzeh item(the tefillin) when we take out the tallit(ibid).

קצז טלית ותפילין הנמצאים בכיס אחד, לסברת האומרים שתפילין חשיבי מוקצה, יש אומרים שאסור להוציא את הטלית מהכיס, שהרי הוא מבטל כלי מהיכנו, שעושה את הכיס הגדול כבסיס לתפילין שהם אסורים בטלטול. אלא צריך קודם להניח ספר בתוך הכיס, ואז יהיה מותר לקחת את הטלית. אך לסברת האומרים שאין לתפילין דין מוקצה, מותר ליקח את הטלית מהכיס. וכן להאומרים שאין דין בסיס לדבר האסור אלא במוקצה מחמת גופו, וכדומה, מותר לקחת את הטלית מהכיס הגדול. והעיקר לדינא להקל בזה, שכל שהבסיס לדבר האסור נעשה מאליו ולא בידים, אין כאן איסור משום מבטל כלי מהיכנו. [על פי דברי המאירי שבת קמב, ובמהדורת תשס''ד עמוד תרמא. ואף שבילקו''י שבת ב' עמוד תפב, נתבאר שהמחמיר ליתן ספר קודם שמוציא את הטלית מהכיס הגדול, תע''ב, הנה כתבנו כן עפ''ד כמה אחרונים, אבל לא ראו את דברי המאירי הנז', שטרם נדפס, ובו נתבאר להדיא להקל].

See here also(http://halacha.co/en/tefillin-on-shabbos/) and footnote 8 there.